# My laptop don't show batery percentage

Tags: battery

PRODUCT NAME: HP x2 Detachable 10-p0XX PRODUCT NUMBER: 1TQ22EA#ABE

I can't view battery percentage on top bar.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get install indicator-power
```

and if it is already installed

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power active true
```